# A3, P3, and T3 - Everything is right and it's not working

Tags: html

I have used this code for a clients subscription based product. 
(Note I have replaced their email just for this post (and for privacy reasons).

I can complete a purchase perfectly fine with OPTION 1 (for $4.99) but OPTION 2 & 3 come up with this error message).

"Invalid Regular period. You must specify valid values for the A3, P3, and T3 parameters for a subscription."

Any suggestions?

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="justin.light15@gmail.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Spark Charger Monthly Member">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="0001">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-SubscriptionsBF:12bd6b_b0853730b2d440d496e35a8988b52895~mv2.png?dn=button-image.png:NonHostedGuest">
    <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Quantity">Quantity
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="os0">
                <option value="1 Charger">1 Charger : $4.99 USD - monthly</option>
                <option value="5 Chargers">5 Chargers : $15.00 USD - monthly</option>
                <option value="10 Chargers">10 Chargers : $25.00 USD - monthly</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="option_select0" value="1 Charger">
    <input type="hidden" name="option_amount0" value="4.99">
    <input type="hidden" name="option_period0" value="M">
    <input type="hidden" name="option_frequency0" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="option_select1" value="5 Charger">
    <input type="hidden" name="option_amount1" value="15.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="option_period1" value="M">
    <input type="hidden" name="option_frequency1" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="option_select2" value="10 Charger">
    <input type="hidden" name="option_amount2" value="25.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="option_period2" value="M">
    <input type="hidden" name="option_frequency2" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="option_index" value="0">
    <br>
    <input type="image" src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/12bd6b_b0853730b2d440d496e35a8988b52895~mv2.png?dn=button-image.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.sparkcharger.com/thank-you">
</form>
```

Comment: The second input element is missing a closing ". It might be one of the reasons. Check this fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/Hema_Nandagopal/vjy2w0e3/10/

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you! Need to make sure im paying close attenion to detail. :)

Comment: Actually false alarm. It doesnt work. I've placed the updated code in the first message above. (This time it has my e mail in their for testing purposes).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the value of the option as well as  the input.

It worked fine for all the three options when I checked.Please Copy the codes and check in your system.

Hope this helps :)

```html
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="justin.light15@gmail.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Spark Charger Monthly Member">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="0001">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-SubscriptionsBF:12bd6b_b0853730b2d440d496e35a8988b52895~mv2.png?dn=button-image.png:NonHostedGuest">
    <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Quantity">Quantity
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="os0">
                <option value="1Charger">1 Charger : $4.99 USD - monthly</option>
                <option value="5Chargers">5 Chargers : $15.00 USD - monthly</option>
                <option value="10Chargers">10 Chargers : $25.00 USD - monthly</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="option_select0" value="1Charger">
    <input type="hidden" name="option_amount0" value="4.99">
    <input type="hidden" name="option_period0" value="M">
    <input type="hidden" name="option_frequency0" value="1">
 
    <input type="hidden" name="option_select1" value="5Chargers">
    <input type="hidden" name="option_amount1" value="15.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="option_period1" value="M">
    <input type="hidden" name="option_frequency1" value="1">
 
    <input type="hidden" name="option_select2" value="10Chargers">
    <input type="hidden" name="option_amount2" value="25.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="option_period2" value="M">
    <input type="hidden" name="option_frequency2" value="1">
 
    <input type="hidden" name="option_index" value="0">
    <br>
    <input type="image" src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/12bd6b_b0853730b2d440d496e35a8988b52895~mv2.png?dn=button-image.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.sparkcharger.com/thank-you">
</form>
```

Comment: Works brilliantly! Thanks!